# "local variables referenced from an inner class must be final or effectively final" in MouseEvent

Tags: java, netbeans, mouseevent, timertask

I am trying to get the integer input from a jtextfield and set it as the integer for a timer jlabel when the jbutton is clicked but I keep getting this error inside the MouseEvent method

> local variables referenced from an inner class must be final or effectively final

Code:

```
    private void timerStartMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                        
        int a = Integer.parseInt(timerInput.getText());
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {         
            public void run() {  
                timeLeft.setText(Integer.toString(a));
                --a;
                if (a == -1){
\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\
                    timer.cancel();                                       
                } else if(isRunning){
\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\
                }
            }
        };
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 1000, 1000);
    }
```

I am still new with Timer Events and Mouse Events, I tried to declare `a` as a global var which still gives me the same error unless I declare it a value within the method but I need to get the input from the jtextfield.

Comment: The short answer is you have to make `a` final.  The longer answer is you can't do that so you need a variable inside the anonymous class instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not tested, but I think this will work.

```
    private void timerStartMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                        
        final int a = Integer.parseInt(timerInput.getText());
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {    
            int localCount = a;     
            public void run() {  
                timeLeft.setText(Integer.toString(localCount));
                --localCount;
                if (localCount == -1){
\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\
                    timer.cancel();                                       
                } else if(isRunning){
\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\
                }
            }
        };
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 1000, 1000);
```

What's going on is that `a` is a local variable and is going to vanish into the ether when this method ends, therefore it's not safe to use.  If the variable is `final` then it's safe for Java to copy the value of `a` into your inner class.  However you need to modify `a` so a constant value won't work.

So we just copy the value into a different variable, one *inside* the inner class.  This makes everything work fine, because now the inner class has its own variable to work with.